# mongodb-java-driver build fails on gradle with :bson:clirr "Cannot cast object 'file collection'"

Tags: java, gradle, mongodb-java

I do have 0.0 experience with gradle/groovy (some maven and sbt experience)

Using documented gradlew instead of gradle fixed the problem, but remains question why is gradle not working and why is gradlew bash file supplied and needed?

I'm trying to build mongodb-java-driver using `gradle check` on Mac OsX. I updated to java 11 (I was still on 1.8), I'm using jenv with the gradle-plugin. I first checkout master, and later on I checked out r3.9.1. First I got one error `Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.` As I rememberd some info on a wrapper when applying jenv apply-gradle-pluging, I renamed wrapper to bwrapper which solved this problem.

Second problem seems harder to solve:

```
Execution failed for task ':bson:clirr'.
> Cannot cast object 'file collection' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.UnionFileCollection' to class 'java.io.File'
```

I tried commenting everything out on bson/gradle.build clirr-task but the problem remains. What goes wrong and what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

mongodb-java-driver need Gradle 4 to build. The project is not compatible with Gradle 5.

Instead, use the gradle wrapper based on version 4.10.2

`./gradlew check`

see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver#build